# Iframe no scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Am having a page with with header and footer which is having a scroll bar already. i need to load dynamic pages to the body content as iframe. Iframe is also having scroll bar. i need to avoid the scroll bar from the iframe without setting the height. Kindly give me any idea.

```
    <!-- page header -->
    <header class="page-header main-page">
    </header>
    <main>
     <iframe src="home.html">
    </main>
    <footer class="page-footer">
    </footer>
```

Comment: if you don't set a height on the iframe, and you don't want the iframe to have a scroll bar inside, how would you see all the content?

Comment: whether there is any way to set auto height without giving any static values?

Comment: @Ajeesh If (as you require), need to avoid the scroll bar within the iframe, I suggest setting the iFrame's `<body>` to have the style `overflow:hidden;` set. However, should the height of the content within the iFrame be bigger that the height that is set by default, it will be a challenge to try navigating around that content within that iFrame.

Comment: Are the pages you are loading in the iframe on the same domain as the main page, or on another domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<iframe src="home.html" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
```

More info. about the `scrolling` attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If iframe page is in same domain:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var elem = document.getElementById("myIframe");
    newheight= elem.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    elem.height = newheight + "px";
</script>
<!-- page header -->
<header class="page-header main-page">
</header>
<main>
 <iframe id="myIframe" src="home.html">
</main>
<footer class="page-footer">
</footer>
```